# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table in Android O

Tags: android

Getting FATAL EXCEPTION in Android O with no such table: APPS_MODEL (code 1): , while compiling: `SELECT * FROM APPS_MODEL WHERE (ACTIVITY_INFO_NAME = ? ) AND (PACKAGE_NAME = ? ) AND (FOLDER_ID = ? ) LIMIT 1`

Working perfectly upto API 25 but when adding API 26 or 27 throws FATAL Exception

here is logcat error info:

> > no such table: APPS_MODEL 03-23 20:33:59.501
> >     7567-7567/com.transformeddev.floatingtoolbox E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
> >     EXCEPTION: main
> >                                                                                       Process: com.transformeddev.floatingtoolbox, PID: 7567
> >                                                                                       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: APPS_MODEL
> >     (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM APPS_MODEL WHERE
> >     (ACTIVITY_INFO_NAME = ? ) AND (PACKAGE_NAME = ? ) AND (FOLDER_ID = ? )
> >     LIMIT 1
> >                                                                                           at
> >     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
> >     Method)
> >                                                                                           at
> >     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
> >                                                                                           at
> >     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
> >                                                                                           at
> >     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
> >                                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
> >                                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
> >                                                                                           at
> >     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
> >                                                                                           at
> >     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1318)
> >                                                                                           at
> >     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1165)
> >                                                                                           at
> >     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1036)
> >                                                                                           at
> >     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1242)
> >                                                                                           at com.orm.SugarRecord.find(SugarRecord.java:192)
> >                                                                                           at com.orm.query.Select.first(Select.java:134)
> >                                                                                           at
> >     com.transformeddev.floatingtoolbox.data.dao.AppsModel.exists(AppsModel.java:141)
> >                                                                                           at
> >     com.transformeddev.floatingtoolbox.ui.modules.apps.device.DeviceAppsPresenter.onAddSelectedApps(DeviceAppsPresenter.java:93)
> >                                                                                           at
> >     com.transformeddev.floatingtoolbox.ui.modules.apps.device.DeviceAppsView.onAddSelectedApps(DeviceAppsView.java:136)
> >                                                                                           at
> >     com.transformeddev.floatingtoolbox.ui.modules.apps.device.DeviceAppsPresenter.onActionItemClicked(DeviceAppsPresenter.java:76)
> >                                                                                           at
> >     android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV9.onActionItemClicked(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1810)
> >                                                                                           at
> >     android.support.v7.view.StandaloneActionMode.onMenuItemSelected(StandaloneActionMode.java:140)
> >                                                                                           at
> >     android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
> >                                                                                           at
> >     android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:171)
> >                                                                                           at
> >     android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:973)
> >                                                                                           at
> >     android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:963)
> >                                                                                           at
> >     android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:624)
> >                                                                                           at
> >     android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:150)
> >                                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
> >                                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697)
> >                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
> >                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
> >                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
> >                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
> >                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> >                                                                                           at
> >     com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
> >                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 03-23
> >     20:33:59.520 1468-1481/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
> >     03-23 20:33:59.570 1468-3059/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize:
> >     unknow param 0x00008cdf 03-23 20:33:59.571 1468-3059/?
> >     E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824

AppsModel Class:

```
public class AppsModel extends SugarRecord implements Parcelable {
    private long folderId;
    private String appName;
    private String packageName;
    private String iconPath;
    private String activityInfoName;
    private int indexPosition;
    private int countEntry;
    @Exclude @Ignore private Bitmap bitmap;

    public AppsModel() {}//default constructor.

    public long getFolderId() {
        return folderId;
    }

    public void setFolderId(long folderId) {
        this.folderId = folderId;
    }

    public String getPackageName() {
        return packageName;
    }

    public void setPackageName(String packageName) {
        this.packageName = packageName;
    }

    public String getIconPath() {
        return iconPath;
    }

    public void setIconPath(String iconPath) {
        this.iconPath = iconPath;
    }

    public String getActivityInfoName() {
        return activityInfoName;
    }

    public void setActivityInfoName(String activityInfoName) {
        this.activityInfoName = activityInfoName;
    }

    public int getIndexPosition() {
        return indexPosition;
    }

    public void setIndexPosition(int indexPosition) {
        this.indexPosition = indexPosition;
    }

    public int getCountEntry() {
        return countEntry;
    }

    public void setCountEntry(int countEntry) {
        this.countEntry = countEntry;
    }

    public String getAppName() {
        return appName;
    }

    public void setAppName(String appName) {
        this.appName = appName;
    }

    @Exclude public ComponentName getComponentName() {
        return new ComponentName(packageName, activityInfoName);
    }

    public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return bitmap;
    }

    public static List<AppsModel> getApps() {
        return Select.from(AppsModel.class)
                .where(Condition.prop(NamingHelper.toSQLNameDefault("folderId")).eq(0))
                .orderBy(NamingHelper.toSQLNameDefault("indexPosition") + " ASC")
                .list();
    }

    public static List<AppsModel> getApps(long folderId) {
        return Select.from(AppsModel.class)
                .where(Condition.prop(NamingHelper.toSQLNameDefault("folderId")).eq(folderId))
                .list();
    }

    public static int lastPosition() {
        AppsModel appsModel = Select.from(AppsModel.class).orderBy(NamingHelper.toSQLNameDefault("indexPosition") + " DESC").first();
        if (appsModel != null) {
            return appsModel.getIndexPosition();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static long countApps(long folderId) {
        return count(AppsModel.class, NamingHelper.toSQLNameDefault("folderId") + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(folderId)});
    }

    public static void deleteAllByFolder(@NonNull FolderModel folder) {
        deleteAll(AppsModel.class, NamingHelper.toSQLNameDefault("folderId") + " = ?", String.valueOf(folder.getId()));
    }

    public static void deleteAll() {
        deleteAll(AppsModel.class);
    }

    public static boolean exists(@NonNull String activityInfoName, @NonNull String packageName) {
        return Select.from(AppsModel.class)
                .where(Condition.prop(NamingHelper.toSQLNameDefault("activityInfoName")).eq(activityInfoName))
                .and(Condition.prop(NamingHelper.toSQLNameDefault("packageName")).eq(packageName))
                .and(Condition.prop(NamingHelper.toSQLNameDefault("folderId")).eq(0))
                .first() != null;
    }

    public static Comparator<AppsModel> sortApps() {
        return new Comparator<AppsModel>() {
            @Override public int compare(AppsModel one, AppsModel two) {
                return one.getAppName().compareTo(two.getAppName());
            }
        };
    }

    @Override public int describeContents() { return 0; }

    @Override public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeLong(this.folderId);
        dest.writeString(this.appName);
        dest.writeString(this.packageName);
        dest.writeString(this.iconPath);
        dest.writeString(this.activityInfoName);
        dest.writeInt(this.indexPosition);
        dest.writeInt(this.countEntry);
        dest.writeValue(this.getId());
    }

    protected AppsModel(Parcel in) {
        this.folderId = in.readLong();
        this.appName = in.readString();
        this.packageName = in.readString();
        this.iconPath = in.readString();
        this.activityInfoName = in.readString();
        this.indexPosition = in.readInt();
        this.countEntry = in.readInt();
        this.setId((Long) in.readValue(Long.class.getClassLoader()));
    }

    public static final Creator<AppsModel> CREATOR = new Creator<AppsModel>() {
        @Override public AppsModel createFromParcel(Parcel source) {return new AppsModel(source);}

        @Override public AppsModel[] newArray(int size) {return new AppsModel[size];}
    };
}
```

Comment: Please format better your question.

Comment: Edited it, if you need more info then tell me.